# How to get multiple unrelated values in the same request with EFCore?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET 6 project with a route that does these requests one after the other:

```cs
var animals = await ctx.Animals.Where(x => TestConditionAnimals(x)).ToListAsync();
var planets = await ctx.Planets.Where(x => TestConditionPlanets(x)).ToListAsync();
var cars = await ctx.Cars.Where(x => TestConditionCars(x)).ToListAsync();
```

But is there a way I can have one `ToListAsync` retrieve all of them?

```cs
var (animals, planets, cars) = await ??????.ToListAsync();
```

I cannot use multiple contexts so everything can be reversed when there is an error.

Comment: Seems like none of those entities are related to each other. I would just leave it as it is. *If* there is a direct relation then you could use joins to bring back related data.

Comment: They are unrelated. I'm looking for an alternative mostly for performance reasons, specially if I need to read more tables at once.